# Why do bitwise 'and', 'xor' and 'or' have different precedences?

Tags: c, bitwise-operators, operator-precedence

What is the reason behind giving &, ^ and | different precedence levels in C? I'm asking for C because most modern languages inherit similar precedence from C. But I don't know much about languages before C. Beside that, it's seems counter-intuitive for me to assign different precedences for operations that are almost identical.

I have heard that, in the beginning C didn't have logical operators. In that case they might had used the same operators for logical and bitwise, and hence they may have ended up with different precedence levels. But in that case, are there any languages, probably existing alongside or before C, which put all three operators at equal precedence?

Comment: Note: & beats | like */ beats +- and certainly for similar reasons.

Comment: This question may seem opinion based.. But I really want to convince myself either 'yes, they are different enough to be placed in different levels' or 'no, it still makes sense even if you place them in same level'.

Comment: "I have heard that, in the beginning C didn't had logical operators." Where did you hear that?

Comment: Fun fact. The standard doesn't mandate some magical hard precedence level here. These are a natural derivation of the [language grammar](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf#page=476) itself (see pages 466 and 467) of the linked draft).

Comment: @4386427 [This](http://www.lysator.liu.se/c/dmr-on-or.html) link. Currently I'm using mobile, and unable to add this link in question.

Comment: @WhozCraig Hmmm.. Sure. But still precedence can be derived from grammer, and also newer languages which are influenced by C also share a similar precedence hierarchy.

Comment: Boolean algebra was studied (invented) long before C. I assume that the math used operator precedence as well and that C just use the same. But that's just my guess.

Comment: @sourav: you have the text of an email from Dennis Ritchie in 1982 in which he explains the origins of the C operator precedence table. You're not going to find a better explanation than that, so I can only conclude that the object of this question is to argue about whether that decision was optimal. That's opinion-based and therefore out of scope here. It's also pointless because the same email admits that the decision might not have been optimal but was made to avoid breaking existing code.

Comment: @rici Okay... what about 'any programming language that follows a different precedence level?'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Disjunctive normal form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjunctive_normal_form)

> In boolean logic, a disjunctive normal form (DNF) is a canonical
> normal form of a logical formula consisting of a disjunction of
> conjunctions; it can also be described as an OR of ANDs, a sum of
> products, or (in philosophical logic) a cluster concept.[citation
> needed] As a normal form, it is useful in automated theorem proving.
>
> [...]
>
> For example, all of the following formulas are in DNF:
>
> - (A ∧ ¬B ∧ ¬C) ∨ (¬D ∧ E ∧ F)

The C equivalent of that example is:

```
(A && !B && !C) || (!D && E && F)
```

Since DNF is a very useful canonical form, it makes sense to make logical AND a higher precedence than logical OR so that the following is a DNF:

```
A && !B && !C || !D && E && F
```

Then it just make sense to follow the same pattern for bitwise and and bitwise or. As for the bitwise xor I can only speculate so I won't do that here.

---

Fun fact: both gcc and clang suggest parentheses around `&&` and `&` to avoid confusion for humans reading the code.

Comment: Yes, exactly, I also didn't get any better reasoning than this. But, (I'm unsure) set theory gives equal precedence to union and intersection I suppose. And I feel bitwise operators are more like them than logical operators. :|